# jQuery filter method confusion

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to filter a jQuery object using the filter method but am not getting the results I expect. Here's my code:

```
var $contents = $(".container");
var $spans = $contents.filter("span");
```

Based on my understanding of the [jQuery filter method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) this should be equivalent to the following:

```
var $spans = $(".container span");
```

However, the first example returns no results into the $spans variable while the second does what I would expect.

Can anyone explain why the first example doesn't return a collection of all the span elements in the container?

Here's a jsfidle illustrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/w8Sf7/

Comment: `.filter()` looks at the elements that are selected. Not at its children. Do you want to select the children of `<div class="container">`?

Comment: Take a look at your modified [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/w8Sf7/1/). Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just looked at the docs and obviously I need to use the children method instead.  Thanks for pointing out the obvious - I needed it!

Answer (score 1):

Filter - is used to filter out your results

```
var $spans = $contents.filter("span"); // <-- filters out the span that are inside $contents collection
```

So the filter is looking for your `$(".container");` elements that are spans

Your filter is equal to

```
var $spans = $("span.container");
```

The other ones

```
var $spans = $(".container span.container"); // <-- gets descendant spans inside .container
```

So this returns any decendant `span` elements of `$(".container");`

So

```
var $spans = $(".container span")
```

Equal to

```
var $spans = $(".container").find('span');
```

Equal to

```
var $spans = $('span',".container");
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are creating a jQuery object which contains a div tag, as there is no selected span element in the set, length is 0.

What you want is `find` or `children` method.

Answer (score 1):

These are equivalent:

```
$contents.filter("span")
$("span.container");
```

As both will find elements which are `span`s with a class of `container`.

Then, these are equivalent:

```
$contents.find("span");
$(".container span")
```

As both will find `span`s which are contained in an element with a class of `container`.

Answer (score 1):

`.filter()` looks at the elements that are selected. Not at its descendants. If you want to select the descendants of `<div class="container">` you can do it a number of ways. Here's how to do it with the `find()`. But this is probably not the most efficient way.

```
var $contents = $(".container");
$contents.find("*").filter("span");
```

These are probably more efficient.

```
$(".container span")
$contents.find("span")
```

And if you want children, then you can use the following.

```
$contents.children("span")
```

There is also the `$(descendantsOfElement, element)` selector. But I think this one is tough to read though when troubleshooting code, so I rarely, if ever, use it.

Comment: It's slightly misleading to say that `find` selects children.  `find` selects descendents, which does have a distinction from children.  `children` selects children.

Comment: Yes. This is true. I will update my post. Thanks for commenting/correcting!